# Переадресация в .htaccess под joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

Доброго времени суток, господа знатоки. Вопрос у меня вот какой:
есть ссылка типа
http://111.com/page-1?view=cpa
Нужно организовать переадресацию, на страницу http://111.com/page-1
Как это реализовать под джумлой в .htaccess. Сам пробовал, что-то у меня не вышло.
Скажите что и как прописывать:

> ```
> ##
> # @version $Id: htaccess.txt 21064 2011-04-03 22:12:19Z dextercowley $
> # @package Joomla
> # @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights
> ```
>
> reserved.
>     # @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
> GNU/GPL
>     # Joomla! is Free Software
>     ##
>     #####################################################
>     #  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
>     #
>     # The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may
> cause problems
>     # with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite,
> but may already
>     # be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows
> changing it in
>     # your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out,
> comment it out (add # to
>     # beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef
> url's.  If they work,
>     # it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it
> set here.
>     #
>     #####################################################
>
> ```
> ##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
> Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> #
> #  mod_rewrite in use
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> ########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
> ## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations
> ```
>
> listed below
>     ## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to
> Joomla!
>     #
>     ## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
>     #<Files ~ ".xml$">
>     #Order allow,deny
>     #Deny from all
>     #Satisfy all
>     #</Files>
>     ## End of deny access to extension xml files
>     # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
>     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
>     # Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
>     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*([^)]*) [OR]
>     # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
>     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
>     # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
>     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
>     # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
>     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
>     # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
>     RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
>     #
>     ########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
>
> ```
> ########## Begin - Custom redirects
> #
> # If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
> # www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
> # redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> flags.
>     #
>
> ```
> ########## End - Custom redirects
>
> #  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
> #  is not directly related to physical file paths.
> #  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)
>
> # RewriteBase /
>
> ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
> #
> RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
> #
> # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
> # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
> # and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
> # requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$
> ```
>
> [NC]
>     # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical
> folder
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
>     RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
>     #
>     ########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот не понимаю почему к оффициальному сайту не обратиться??

например: [вот](http://joomlaportal.ru/content/view/100/53/) или [вот](http://sirega.ru/sozdanie-chpu-v-joomla-25.html)